# Minors and CDC Attestation requirements

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, covid-19, attestation

We're traveling back to the US tomorrow and have been asked to complete the CDC Attestation Form. On this form it says minors (ages 2-17) are excepted from the vaccination requirement but are expected to test 3-5 days after entry or isolate for 5 days. We have a 9yo.

We are leaving the US the same day (by land), or next day at the latest - which of these options should I select, or should I put something else and try to discuss it at  immigration?

Comment: This form is retained by your airline and not discussed at immigration. I wouldn't suggest lying on the form but, um, as a practical matter, nobody is going to be paying very much attention to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check both boxes in section D

> I attest that I am or the person I am attesting on behalf of is excepted from the requirement to present
> Proof of Being Fully Vaccinated Against COVID 19 and made the following arrangements **(must check all
> boxes in D and then sign Attestation**)

The first box attest that you (or your child) will test 3-5 days after arrival and the second box attests that you (or your child) will self isolate and wear a mask **IF** the test is positive or you develop symptoms.

Chances are no one will follow up with you and if you are out of the country you are out of the country. This being said, in general it's a good idea to do what you said: testing after travel is a good precaution and if your child tests positive, you should indeed isolate them for a while.

Comment: Many nations have now changed the status of COVID to that of the common flu, so if you're going to get tested you should also get a test for flu and RSV.

Answer (score 1):

> We are leaving the US the same day (by land), or next day at the latest - which of these options should I select, or should I put something else and try to discuss it at immigration?

Doesn't really matter but I'd put down the "test" option as the more reasonable one. This rule hasn't been enforced for even a single day and immigration will not ask you about it. It's just a bit of a leftover security theater, set to expire in [May 11th](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/02/09/the-covid-emergency-in-the-us-ends-may-11-hhs-officials-say-heres-what-to-expect.html) when the pandemic is scheduled to be officially over in the United States.

Comment: Is this the same US that scheduled Real ID enforcement to begin -- also on May 11th -- in 2008?  They haven't shown themselves to be very good at sticking to schedules.  Speaking of security theater.

Comment: @phoog they haven't been good of *starting* a security theater :-) I'm confident they'll be able to *end* one on schedule. Masks are already gone from hospitals in my state so I think there's no going back.